Converting formatted data without geometry definitions from CSV into TIFF
I am trying to convert thermal image data from a CSV format into a TIF. The FLIR software outputs the thermal image data as a .csv file which is formatted as below:
33.5,32.3,31.0,30.3,30.5,29.9,29.9,28.9,28.5,28.3,27.8,27.4,27.4,27.5,27.5,27.5,27.4,27.4,27.5,27.6,27.4,27.6,27.2,27.5,27.4,27.1,27.1,26.9,26.7,26.7,26.8,26.5,26.2,26.4,26.1,25.5,25.5,24.8,23.9,23.3,23.0,22.8,23.4,23.6,23.6,23.9,25.4,27.1,28.7,30.1,31.8,34.2,37.2,38.8,40.2,40.3,40.9,41.9,42.6,41.0,36.7,34.5,32.6,31.2,31.0,30.6,29.5,28.9,28.6,28.0,28.5,28.7,28.2,28.3,28.3,28.3,27.6,28.0,27.4,26.9,27.2,27.1,27.4,27.4,27.4,26.9,26.8,26.8,27.2,27.6,27.8,28.2,28.3,28.3,28.2,27.8,28.2,28.0,27.9,27.8,27.8,27.9,27.8,28.0,28.3,28.2,28.2,28.3,28.2,28.2,28.3,28.3,28.0,28.2,28.6,28.5,28.3,28.3,28.9,29.0,28.9,29.4,29.1,28.7,28.6,28.5,28.2,28.5,28.3,28.6,28.6,28.6,28.6,28.2,28.2,28.5,28.6,29.1,29.5,29.1,29.1,28.7,28.3,28.3,28.2,28.2,27.9,27.8,28.0,28.2,28.3,27.9,27.9,27.4,27.4,27.4,26.5,25.9,25.5,25.4,25.8,26.1,27.1,27.8,29.0,31.1,32.9,33.9,35.0,36.4,38.8,40.5,41.3,41.3,40.5,39.6,37.2,33.9,31.9,31.2,30.5,30.2,30.2,31.0,31.6,32.3,32.3,31.5,30.7,29.9,29.5,29.4,29.0,28.9,28.9,29.0,28.6,28.5,29.0,29.4,29.4,29.0,28.3,28.2,27.8,27.6,28.3,29.1,30.1,31.2,32.6,33.9,35.8,38.0,39.1,39.9,39.4,38.2,36.5,34.5,33.1,32.6,32.0,32.1,31.4,30.6,30.2,29.4,29.1,29.0,29.1,29.5,29.7,29.7,29.4,29.1,28.6,28.2,27.8,27.8,27.9,28.2,28.7,29.1,29.1,28.7,28.3,28.3,28.2,28.2,28.2,28.2,28.6,28.7,28.2,27.9,27.8,28.2,28.7,29.0,28.7,28.6,28.3,28.2,28.2,28.6,28.7,29.0,29.7,29.8,29.9,29.4,28.6,28.3,28.3,28.2,28.2,28.2,28.5,28.3,27.9,27.6,28.0,28.2,28.0,27.9,28.0,28.3,28.2,28.3,28.2,28.0,28.0,28.2,28.6,28.3,28.6,28.6,28.6,28.6,28.6,28.5,28.3,28.5,28.6,28.7,28.6,28.5,28.5,28.6,28.6,29.0,29.0,28.7,28.6,27.9,27.6,27.4,27.1,27.2,26.9,27.2,28.0,30.1,33.1,35.7,36.8,38.0,40.0,40.7,40.5,39.7,39.7,40.2,40.9,42.0,42.7,43.3,42.6,42.6,42.6,42.2,42.3,42.9,43.2,42.5,39.9,36.6,36.4,38.0,39.3,40.3,39.9,38.8,37.2,36.1,35.7,36.5,38.0,39.6,40.7,41.0,41.3,41.0,40.7,40.7,40.6,41.0,41.0,40.5,40.7,40.6,40.0,39.4,39.4,40.3,41.2,41.7,41.0,40.6,40.7,41.0,41.7,42.9,43.0,42.1,41.0,40.5,40.5,41.6,42.0,42.3,42.9,42.0,40.9,40.3,39.6,39.6,40.2,40.3,40.5,41.3,41.9,41.3,40.8,41.7,42.3,41.1,39.9,39.6,39.6,39.5,40.2,40.8,40.9,40.5,41.1,42.3,42.9,43.9,44.1,43.9,43.7,43.3,42.9,42.7,43.6,43.4,41.7,40.1,39.3,39.3,39.9,40.5,41.3,42.1,42.0,42.6,43.0,42.9,42.5,41.9,41.7,42.7,42.7,42.3,41.8,41.2,41.5,42.3,42.5,43.1,43.5,43.2,43.2,42.8,43.3,44.2,44.9,45.0,43.7,43.5,43.6,43.6,43.5,44.5,45.8,45.5,45.8,45.8,45.5,45.6,45.9,45.9,45.8,45.7,46.6,47.1,47.6,48.0,47.0,44.8,43.4,43.6,44.1,45.1,45.4,44.7,43.8,40.8,35.9,33.1,32.3,31.5,31.0,30.6,28.7,27.4,27.1,27.1,26.9,26.9,26.7,26.7,26.8,27.5,28.2,29.8,31.8,30.6,29.0,27.4,27.1,26.8,27.1,27.2,27.1,26.7,26.8,26.8,26.7,26.5,26.5,26.2,26.4,26.7,26.5,26.5,26.5,26.1,25.9,25.9,25.9,25.9,25.9,25.9,26.1,26.8,27.2,27.2,27.2,26.9,27.1,26.7,26.5,26.1,25.9,26.1,25.9,26.2,26.1,26.2,26.7,26.5,26.4,26.1,26.7,26.5,26.7,26.8,27.1,26.9,26.5,26.4,26.4,26.7,26.5,26.7,26.1,25.7,25.2,25.4,25.5,26.2,27.2,26.9,26.8,26.8,26.7,26.9,26.7,26.2,25.8,25.4,25.8,25.5,25.5,25.8,25.8,26.7,28.2,30.7,34.7,36.9,37.5,38.0,37.2,36.4,37.5,38.1,38.0,37.4,38.6,38.6,38.2,38.3,39.0,39.6,39.0,38.8,39.6,39.6,39.6,39.3,41.0,41.3,41.3,41.8,42.1,43.1,42.3,40.7,39.6,40.1,39.9,40.5,41.7,40.2,40.6,40.6,40.7,42.3,44.9,44.3,43.2,42.6,42.5,42.6,42.3,42.7
35.2,34.5,32.5,31.0,29.7,28.9,29.4,29.8,29.0,28.2,27.6,27.1,27.4,27.5,27.5,27.4,27.2,27.1,27.4,27.2,27.6,27.5,27.2,27.2,27.2,26.8,26.8,26.9,26.7,26.4,26.2,26.2,25.9,25.9,25.5,25.8,25.5,25.1,24.5,23.7,23.3,23.3,23.6,23.7,23.6,24.5,25.8,27.4,28.0,29.8,33.0,36.3,37.7,38.9,39.0,39.2,40.2,40.7,40.4,37.7,34.8,33.4,32.1,31.0,31.5,31.0,30.2,29.8,29.0,28.5,28.7,28.7,28.2,28.0,28.6,28.3,28.2,28.0,27.6,27.2,27.2,27.1,27.1,27.2,27.1,27.2,26.7,27.1,27.4,28.0,27.8,28.2,28.3,28.3,28.0,28.0,28.3,28.0,27.6,27.4,27.4,27.8,28.0,28.2,28.0,28.0,28.0,28.5,28.3,28.3,28.2,28.0,27.8,28.0,28.3,28.3,28.2,28.5,28.6,28.6,29.0,29.5,29.0,28.9,29.0,28.6,28.3,28.5,28.0,28.3,28.7,28.7,28.5,28.2,28.3,28.2,28.6,29.0,29.1,29.1,28.9,28.6,28.7,28.9,28.5,28.3,28.0,27.6,27.6,27.8,28.0,27.8,27.6,27.4,27.5,27.1,26.7,26.1,25.4,25.5,26.2,27.4,28.0,28.7,29.8,31.2,32.3,32.9,34.8,37.1,39.2,40.9,41.3,41.3,41.6,40.5,38.3,34.7,32.9,32.0,31.6,31.2,30.7,31.0,31.4,32.3,32.5,32.0,31.1,30.7,30.3,29.8,29.0,28.7,28.5,28.6,28.6,28.7,29.1,29.9,29.9,29.8,28.9,28.5,28.2,28.3,28.9,29.7,30.5,31.9,33.1,34.7,36.3,38.0,39.2,39.9,39.6,38.5,36.6,34.4,33.1,32.0,31.4,31.5,32.0,31.9,30.7,30.3,29.9,29.8,29.7,29.8,30.2,30.2,29.9,29.1,28.7,28.6,28.3,27.9,27.9,28.6,29.0,29.5,29.5,29.5,29.1,28.6,28.0,28.2,28.0,28.2,28.3,28.6,28.3,28.0,28.0,28.2,29.0,29.1,29.1,29.1,28.9,28.3,28.5,28.6,28.9,29.0,29.9,30.3,30.1,29.8,29.5,29.4,28.7,28.3,28.3,28.3,28.6,28.6,28.2,27.9,27.8,27.8,28.0,27.8,27.9,28.3,28.3,28.3,28.2,28.0,28.0,28.3,28.0,28.0,28.0,28.3,28.7,28.6,28.6,28.6,28.5,28.6,29.0,28.7,28.3,28.3,28.2,28.3,28.3,28.7,29.1,28.7,28.5,28.0,28.0,27.9,27.6,26.8,26.7,26.8,27.6,30.5,34.1,36.4,37.7,37.9,39.1,40.2,40.8,40.7,40.7,41.2,41.7,42.6,43.4,43.5,42.6,42.1,42.0,42.0,42.5,42.8,42.3,41.3,39.1,35.4,33.4,34.0,36.3,38.2,39.2,39.2,38.8,38.0,37.3,37.2,38.5,39.9,40.5,40.7,40.7,40.5,40.2,40.3,40.3,40.5,40.7,40.3,40.3,40.1,40.1,40.2,40.5,40.9,41.1,41.3,40.8,40.5,40.3,40.8,41.3,42.3,42.9,42.1,40.8,40.7,41.3,42.2,42.2,42.3,42.7,42.2,41.2,40.5,40.4,40.3,40.5,40.4,40.4,41.1,41.9,41.3,40.7,41.5,42.1,41.6,40.5,39.3,39.4,39.6,40.0,40.2,40.9,41.0,41.1,41.7,42.9,43.3,43.4,43.3,43.3,43.1,42.9,43.6,44.1,43.1,41.0,39.6,39.2,39.1,40.3,41.3,41.8,42.0,42.1,42.8,43.6,43.4,43.1,42.5,41.8,42.6,42.9,42.3,41.7,41.5,41.3,41.7,42.1,42.4,42.9,42.6,42.7,42.8,43.2,43.9,43.9,44.1,44.2,43.9,44.2,44.6,44.5,44.7,45.2,45.2,46.4,46.9,45.9,45.4,46.0,45.8,45.1,45.6,46.0,46.4,47.0,47.8,47.4,45.6,44.0,44.0,44.6,44.6,45.0,44.2,42.9,40.9,36.4,33.9,32.9,32.9,31.9,30.3,29.5,27.6,27.2,27.1,26.8,26.7,26.7,26.4,26.8,27.1,27.6,28.3,29.0,28.3,27.8,27.1,26.8,26.8,27.4,27.1,27.1,27.1,26.9,27.1,26.7,26.4,26.5,26.5,26.1,26.2,26.7,26.7,26.7,26.1,26.1,25.8,25.9,25.9,25.9,26.1,26.5,26.9,27.1,27.1,27.1,26.5,26.7,26.7,26.2,26.1,25.7,25.7,25.9,25.9,26.1,26.1,26.2,26.2,26.1,26.1,26.7,26.4,26.4,26.2,26.7,26.8,26.4,26.4,26.2,26.2,26.5,26.5,26.1,25.9,25.4,25.4,25.7,26.1,26.8,27.4,27.2,27.1,26.5,26.8,26.9,26.2,25.8,25.5,25.8,25.4,25.1,25.5,25.9,26.7,28.0,30.5,33.9,36.7,37.4,37.4,36.9,36.9,37.4,37.4,38.0,38.1,38.4,38.5,38.4,38.8,39.3,40.0,39.1,38.5,39.3,39.9,40.2,39.6,41.1,41.7,41.3,42.0,42.0,43.0,43.0,41.3,39.1,39.1,39.2,41.0,41.2,40.7,41.3,41.3,40.8,41.5,44.0,44.7,44.1,43.1,42.0,41.7,42.4,42.3
This is a very small section of the data to illustrate the formatting - Each row is composed of comma-separated values, with each row separated by a return. When opened with Excel and using conditional formatting, it can be visualised as each cell being a single pixel making up the image (which is 640 values/pixels by 512 values/pixels.

I need to convert this csv data into TIFs, but all the solutions I have found require column headers, such as x/y or lat/long which this data is missing. Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

I don't believe there are any coordinates (except for pixel position in the image grid) so this is probably not a GIS topic at all. A little python script should be fairly easy to do: ask Stackexchange, find examples or ask an LLM (gives 8 lines as a sample code).

Read into a numpy array, save as an image

I think that the numpy route that @Bera suggested is better, but you can do what you want also with a text editor and gdal_translate.
First, find out how many rows and columns you have in the data and have a look at how ESRI AsciiGrid files are written https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/autotest/gdrivers/data/aaigrid/nodata_float.asc
Add header lines at the beginning of the text file with these values:
ncols        what-you-have-in-data
nrows        what-you-have-in-data
xllcorner    0
yllcorner    0
cellsize     1

Change the commas between the cell values into spaces. The linefeeds can stay as they are. These both small test files seem to work in the same way.
asciitest1.asc
==============
ncols        5
nrows        2
xllcorner    0
yllcorner    0
cellsize     1
1 2 3 4,5
6 7 8 9 10

asciitest2.asc
==============
ncols        5
nrows        2
xllcorner    0
yllcorner    0
cellsize     1
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

Test with gdalinfo:
gdalinfo asciitest.asc
Driver: AAIGrid/Arc/Info ASCII Grid
Files: asciitest.asc
Size is 5, 2
Origin = (0.000000000000000,2.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (1.000000000000000,-1.000000000000000)
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (   0.0000000,   2.0000000)
Lower Left  (   0.0000000,   0.0000000)
Upper Right (   5.0000000,   2.0000000)
Lower Right (   5.0000000,   0.0000000)
Center      (   2.5000000,   1.0000000)
Band 1 Block=5x1 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Undefined

Convert into TIFF:
gdal_translate asciitest2.asc asciitest2.tif
Input file size is 5, 2
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.

